# Multi Threads write multi files,But it will affect each other

Tags: java, multithreading, io

When I run a single thread to write into a file,it takes around 400 milliseconds ,but I run three or more threads,every thread write a file,it takes around 1000 milliseconds,all of these threads change slowed,how does it happen?

here is my code

```
package practice.feature.java.core.thread;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;

public class MainEnter {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        WriteFile file1 = new WriteFile("WriteFile" + i + ".txt");
        new Thread(file1).start();
    }
}

static class WriteFile implements Runnable {
    private String name;

    public WriteFile(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
        File file = new File(name);
        try {
            file.createNewFile();
            FileWriter versionWriter = new FileWriter(file, true);
            for (long i = 0; i < 1000000L; i++) {
                versionWriter.write(name + "****" + i);
                versionWriter.write(System.getProperty("line.separator"));

            }
            versionWriter.flush();
            versionWriter.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Long newnow1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println(name + "导出时间：" + (newnow1 - now));
    }
}
}
```

Comment: A disk can only write to one place at a time. Alternating between writing 3 different files on disk in 3 different places is slower than doing each sequentially. It's just not a task which lends itself to parallelism. SSDs might perform okay, but a HDD will suffer because the r/w head has to physically move back and forth, and this is effectively just wasted time.

Comment: A small note: A `Long` creates an object in this case but `long` doesn't and is notionally faster.

Comment: In fact all this "back and forth" even gets to be audible in most cases.  If your disk is not in a room miles away, that is.

Answer (score 0):

When you close a file it is flushed to disk by the OS.  I suspect you have an HDD which is typically limited to about 40 MB/s. Writing more files at once can get you closer to the disk's maximum bandwidth but you don't see a significant improvement.

NOTE: an SSD is faster but a typical drive is still limited to about 500 MB/s

In short, adding more threads doesn't speed up your disk drive.